# Why pages are not generated for a site created with --blank?

Tags: jekyll

*Note: I may have hit an edge case for Jekyll running in a Linux for Windows 10 environment. The same data used on pure Windows or in pure Linux work as expected (after the modifications following @marcanuy's answer). I will be back after more testing.*

I created a new site via

```
jekyll new myblog --blank
```

This created the expected structure in `myblog`. I added a template `_layouts/docs.html`

```
<h1>hello world</h1>

{{ content }}
```

I then created a `_posts/hello.md` file:

```
---
title = the hello world page
layout = docs
---

# this is a hello world page

Hello world everyone
```

After running

```
# jekyll build
Configuration file: none
            Source: /root/myblog
       Destination: /root/myblog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.03 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

my `_site` folder is empty, except for an `index.html` file copied from the root of my blog (copied verbatim - this is the content I put in `index.html` in the root)

**Why isn't `hello.html` generated?** I expected it to contain

```
<h1>hello world</h1>

<h1>this is a hello world page</h1>

Hello world everyone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that makes jekyll not build the "hello" page:

## filename

- if you put `hello.md` inside the `_posts` folder, then the correct filename should contain post's date like: `2017-05-21-hello.md`

Then it will be available:

```
.
├── _drafts
├── index.html
├── _layouts
│   └── docs.html
├── _posts
│   └── 2017-05-21-hello.md
└── _site
    ├── hello.html
    └── index.html
```

Another approach is to publish it as a `page`:

- in `/hello.md`, i.e.: at root level (not inside `/_posts`)

  ```
  .
  ├── _drafts
  ├── hello.md
  ├── index.html
  ├── _layouts
  │   └── docs.html
  ├── _posts
  └── _site
  ├── hello.html
  └── index.html
  ```

## frontmatter

The other problem is the syntax of the front matter of `hello.md`, each attribute should be defined with `:` instead of `=`:

```
---
title: the hello world page
layout: docs
---

# this is a hello world page

Hello world everyone
```

Comment: Thank you. The naming was indeed wrong (for future reference: this is [clearly documented](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#creating-post-files), as was the [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) (I am coming from Hugo and missed this part). I ran the build again but the `_site` folder still does not have the generated page.

Comment: I also tried another `testing.md` file in the root of my blog, did not get generated either. OTOH a `something.txt` file in the root got copied to `_site`. Maybe the markdown converter does not work? (but there are no error messages in the build process)

Comment: If it has the three dotted lines `---` then jekyll will process it, with the process described in the answer then it should work. Try renaming it as `hello.html` at the root level to help debugging it or create a new one.

Comment: I may have hit an edge case for Jekyll running in a Linux for Windows 10 environment. The same data used on pure Windows or in pure Linux work as you mentioned.